# Computer loads BIOS, but won't load OS

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios, desktop-computer

I have just purchased a brand new motherboard bundle, installed into the old case with the old PSU and the old HDD.  I can get into the BIOS, but whenever I try to boot from the HDD, it just sits with the fans going, but nothing is displayed.
The moniter works (tested with another machine), and I'd hope there are no problems with the motherboard, CPU or RAM because as I said I only brought them today.
The only things I can think of are:

- The PSU's motherboard connector is a 20-pin, and the motherboard has a 24-pin connector (not a problem with the previous board)
- The OS is not supported (doesn't seem likly to me, but possible I guess)

Here is my system configuration:

- Motherboard: ASUS F1A55-M le
- CPU: AMD APU A6 3500
- HDD: 1Tb SATA
- RAM: 4Gb DDR3
- OS: Ubuntu Satanic v666.9
- PSU: Winpower ATX-400 (this thing is REALLY old)

If anyone is able to offer a reason as to why this is not working, or a possible solution, it would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Does the PSU have one of those 4-pin connectors?  It's probably hanging off the 20-pin connector if there is one, that goes into the last 4 pins on the mobo.  Can you boot from _anything_?  For example, could you boot from an install CD or live USB key?

Comment: Does your bios detect your hdd?

Comment: @Mxx yes the HDD is detected.  I load the BIOS, select 'boot from HDD', then nothing.

Comment: So does your BIOS go through the whole post process but gets stuck at the point where it's supposed to be boot from hdd? Can you boot from CD/DVD or USB? That will help narrowing down if this is a problem booting from hdd or booting in general.

Comment: @ChimneyImp It has a seperate 4-pin connector that plugs into its own socket on the motherboard.  Unfortunatly, my old CD/DVD drive has an IDE connection, and the new motherboard doesn't, so can't try that.  I'll try the USB thing now and post back the results.

Comment: @Mxx I don't know what you mean...  I tell it to load from the HDD, then the monitor goes to standby mode (which it does when there is no signal), and all the fans keep going.  Also, the connector for the case speaker is not compatible (the case is as ancient al the PSU) so I'm not hearing any beeps at all (don't know if that's relevant).

Comment: Does the HDD have an OS installed on it? Can you boot from a CD/DVD or USB device? Can you change the SATA device speed in the BIOS?? (Slow it down or change it to an ATA/IDE speed and try again)

Comment: @PenguinCoder Please read before posting.  I have stated in the original question that the OS is Ubuntu Satanic edition, and in the comments that there is no CD/DVD drive.  The HDD speed is already set to IDE, though not sure how the speed would affect it.  Currently creating a live USB stick to try, will post the results when it's done.

Comment: It actually might be a problem with the lack of pins on the power connector. They are there for providing more current. It is possible the BIOS works, but when it goes to boot, it it being "starved for power."

Comment: Just tried the USB thing with Ubuntu 11.10.  It gets to the screen where I can choose to run from USB, install from USB, ect.  When I select to run from the USB it just acts as above.  Gonna try getting a new PSU with the 24-pin connector, see if that helps.  Thanks for all your suggestions people :)

Comment: ChimneyImp and horatio are correct. Just because you got lucky with the previous motherboard and CPU and were able to run it with only a 20-pin PSU instead of a 24-pin PSU that the board was designed for, does not mean that this one will work. You will need to use a PSU with a 24-pin motherboard connector.

Comment: What is almost certainly happening is that the PSU is able to provide the CPU with what it needs for the basic POST/BIOS functions, but once you start trying to actually boot an OS, the CPU is either running too hard and trying to draw more power than the PSU can supply, or is doing some sort of initialization routine that fails when it does not get supplementary power from the extra 4-pins. That certainly fits the description you gave about the system going out and the video signal shutting off.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the drivers that are loading from your HDD are for the old Mobo and are not compatible for the new Mobo.  I found this, but cannot confirm the accuracy or reliability:

1. get a Hirens boot cd
2. boot into the mini xp Provided on Hirens
   3.In the hirens utilities, Find registry tools, and click on FIX hdd controller
   It launches a dos window, where you select your target root, and choose repair.
   It seems to delete the old driver out of current control set 00 from your registry, and replace it with generic version.

Good luck!

Comment: The OP runs Ubuntu Satanic Linux, not Windows.